# Console use CAPS for user input

Tags: c#, input, capitalization

I'm creating a Tic Tac Toe game as a console application using C# (which I am still learning). I want to know if it is possible to change the user input from an `x` to a capital `X` because it looks better.

Comment: Do you mean as he enters it, or after he enters it?

Comment: as he enters it so the small x wont be seen, just the capitalized X

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change a string to its capitalised representation using

```
.ToUpper();
```

EDIT - To change it in the console window I'd use this instead:

```
Console.ReadKey(false)
```

will hide the pressed key from the console window, then you can write it yourself in capitals.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3h8xffw.aspx

Comment: After reading the question again, this doesn't seem to answer the questiom.

Comment: But when the user is pressing x it is already displaying in the console as an "x"

Comment: Hmm, I assumed he wanted it to display the input in a capitalised format. Reading it again it could be he wants to change the input shown in the console. We'll wait for the OP to respond.